# Extract value from JDBC request and use in next jdbc requests

Tags: jdbc, jmeter, request, variable-assignment

In my test plan I have 3 JDBC request.
In the first of them, I insert a row and get the row_id, so charge this row_id on the variable _row_id for use it in next tests.

[image]

In the second of them, I can catch this variable correctly with '${_row_id_1}' and update the row, but in the third test the value of '${_row_id_1}' change to 'true'.

[image]

How I can keep the value of variable for next tests?

Answer (score 0):

Remove everything from "Variable Names" section of the `update 2` request because you're **overwriting** the variables from the previous request there.

Alternatively give these variables new unique names.

You can inspect which JMeter Variables are generated with their respective value using [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter) (or [Debug PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_PostProcessor)) and [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) combination.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, I will test your options.
In "variable names" section, I changed _row_id for _row_id_1 and it works!